# google charts dataView format differently from the dataSource?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I've created a dataView in order to put a label on my Google bar chart like :

```
 options = {
                title: arr[0][0],
                titleTextStyle: { fontSize: '12', color: '#666' },
                colors: ['#50c0ed'],
                backgroundColor: { fill: 'transparent' },
                height: 220,
                width: '100%',
                is3D: true,
                fontSize: '11',
                hAxis: { format: '$###,###,###.00' },
                vAxis: {
                    format: '$###,###,###.##',
                viewWindow: {
                    min: 0
                    }
            },
                chartArea: { width: '100%', height: '60%', top: '40', left: '65', right: '10' },
                tooltip: { textStyle: { color: '#333', fontSize: '11' } }
            };
            formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: '$###,###.##/SF/year' });
            formatter.format(data, 1);`enter code here`
            view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1,
                {
                    calc: "stringify",
                    sourceColumn: 1,
                    type: "string",
                    role: "annotation",
                }]);

            chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container[0]);
```

and the result is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzHSV.png) , but i want to exclude from the label the /SF/year ending but still keep it when i hoover over the bar ,
I tried to set formatter only after i initialize the dataVIew but this doesen't work , Is there i way i can remove /SF/year from the label but keep it when i hoover over ?

Answer (score 0):

use another formatter without --> `/SF/year`

```
formatterNumberOnly = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: '$###,###.##' });
```

then in `view`, use custom `calc` function instead of `"stringify"`
use `formatValue` method to format the value of each row

```
view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return formatterNumberOnly.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 1));
    },
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation",
}]);
```